# How to use IF value equals/unequals any of the values in a column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So i have table:

[image]

and here is code: `

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ip_check (ip_check_address, ip_check_id) VALUES ($encode , $id)");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$encode = ip2long($ip);
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["keywordid"]);
$check_id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ip_check_id FROM ip_check 
WHERE ip_check_address = $encode");
if ($check_id != $id ) {..}
```

`

I need to check if ip_check_id is already used.

Comment: If that's meant to be a unique identifier for the check, then either put a unique constraint on your field and/or make it an auto-incrementing value. Alternatively, do a select from the table first to see if the id you're about to insert already exists.

Comment: So how to like check if value equals any of the values in a column? Right now IF ($check_id != $id ) is TRUE, where $id is 8.

Comment: *"I need to check if ip_check_id is already used."* - You can use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) - Plus, you'll need to quote your IP value `WHERE ip_check_address = '$encode'");` as IP addresses contain periods/dots.

Comment: mysqli_num_rows just counts how many rows there is in the column. I need to check if $id is equal to any value in the column. And $encode is used to encode ip address

Comment: @Art4k OK. Let me edit my answer. Give me a minute.

Comment: @Art4k I edited my answer below, please reload it to see the changes.

Comment: I just noticed you accepted my answer, then un-accepted, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
$check_id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ip_check_id FROM ip_check 
WHERE ip_check_address = $encode");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_id))
    {
         $check_if_exist = $row['ip_check_id'];

         if ($check_if_exist != $id ) 
        {

            // it does not equal
        }


    }
```

---

*Origninal answer, I misunderstood the question.*

> *"I need to check if ip_check_id is already used."*

---

***Sidenote:***

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given  on line 25:  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array())

Comment: @Art4k I forgot the query parameter variable, and I renamed a few variables in case of conflicts. Please reload.

Comment: Still same problem :/ print_r($check_if_exist); just gives the same  as $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["keywordid"]);

Comment: I think the problem may be with `htmlspecialchars` that is mostly used for viewing purposes and not for possible SQL prevention, is that what you want to use `htmlspecialchars` for? @Art4k Try removing it `$id = $_GET["keywordid"];`

Comment: $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["keywordid"]); working good with sql(tested), i need to check if $id already in ip_check_id column(see picture above) like if user come to page.php?id=2 and $id is 2(because $_GET["keywordid"]). Then sql checks if there is no ip with the same id and counts as unique visitor.

Comment: @Art4k Is `page.php?id=2` what you're actually using or is that just an example? I tend to think that you are using `page.php?keywordid=2` correct? I tested my original answer and it worked. At this point, am under the impression you want to check if one column with a certain number matches another inside another column.

Comment: yes i'm using keywordid. You see there is numbers in column eg(8,8,9,9,10) when i'm coming from page.php?keywordid=8 SQL need to check IF (column numbers != keywordid)

Comment: @Art4k Just do the reverse of `if($check_if_exist == $id )` and do `if($check_if_exist != $id )`

Comment: $check_if_exist gives the same value as page.php?id= . Is there is any command to call ip_check_id column to print rows like 8,8,9,9,10? I have an idea.

Comment: @Art4k Sorry, at this point, I don't know what to suggest. If you want to print the rows, just do `echo $row['column_you_want_to_echo'];` in the loop.

Comment: how to comma-separate them?

Comment: Modify your query to be `SELECT ip_check_id, GROUP_CONCAT(the_column_you_want) FROM ip_check` @Art4k

Answer (score 1):

```
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ip_check (ip_check_address, ip_check_id) 
    VALUES ($encode , $id)");

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $encode = ip2long($ip);
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["keywordid"]);
    $check_id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ip_check_id FROM ip_check 
    WHERE ip_check_address = $encode");
    $query = @mysqli_query($check_id);


    while($row = @mysqli_fetch_array())
    {
         $check_id = $row['ip_check_id'];

         if ($check_id== $id ) 
        {

            //here it is equal, returns ture
        }
        else
        {
        // here returns false
        }
    }
```

Comment: not working :( if($check_id != $id) is a TRUE and if($check_id == $id) FALSE :/ it's like if(8 != 8) TRUE and if (9 == 8) FALSE.

Comment: -1 You're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_array` - they do **not** mix. Who upvoted this in the first place?

Comment: I edited your answer and removed my -1. Remember that `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions do not mix together.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that i in mysqli, merely trying to give the gentleman a working idea, did not focus on givving the accurate code, as you may see merely the approach